# Directives in an Angular2 Component

Tags: rest, angular

I am trying to follow this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7xPwhwbcHE&t=241s on using HTTP Rest calls in an Angular 2 application.

When I reach the point of including the directives in the @Component annotation, I get this error:

```
Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; directives: typeof HttpTestComponent[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.
```

I don't know what exact version of Angular2 I'm using, neither to I know how to find out, bit is this likely down to an incompatibility between the version used in the tutorial, and my version? How can I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

That's pre-final code. Since final `directives` and `pipes` from `@Component()` go to

```
@NgModule({
  delcarations: [...]
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html